# Moving files between C: drive and virtual machiene

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, file-transfer

I have set up a shared folder to transfer files between my virtual machine and my desktop. The shared folder is set to everyone and under the Virtualbox - settings - shared folders I can see the folder I am trying to share things through but once I boot up I cannot see the folder. Any suggestions on what to correct so I can see the folder?

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to do and what your situation is. What OS is your VM? What is the host OS? Is the shared folder on the VM or host?

Answer (score 2):

On the VirtualBox machine, go to `\\VBOXSVR\<Share_Folder_Name>`, where `<Share_Folder_Name>` is the name that you have setup in the *Share Folders* section in the VM settings.

If you are using Windows XP as the virtual machine, you can also browse to the share folder in Windows Explorer via:

```
My Network Places -> Entire Network -> VirtualBox Shared Folders -> \\Vboxsvr -> <Share_Folder_Name>
```